# Get php function value from javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Allow me to preface this by saying that I did look over other answers, but I am still uncertain how to execute it.

Here is my problem:

I have a .txt file from which I am reading and parsing the meaning of a name (I know, DB is better, but this is what I was given). I wish to fetch the return value of my php function into my javascript function. How would I go about doing this?

PHP Code:

```
function populateMeaning() {
    $meanings = fopen("meanings.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file");
    $meaning = "";

    $selectOption = $_POST['allnames'];

    while(!feof($meanings)) {
        $selectOption = strtoupper($selectOption);
        $line = fgets($meanings);

        if(strpos($line,$selectOption ) !== false) {
            $meaning = substr($line, strpos(0, ' '), strlen($line));
        }
    }

    return $meaning;
}
```

Javascript function in question:

```
function meaning(){

    document.getElementById("meaning").innerHTML = "hello";
}
```

So I have a div element titled "meaning" and I would like to replace it's inner html value. The string "hello" is currently simply a placeholder to make sure that the JS is called correctly.

Comment: Simply, with AJAX.

Comment: [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: AJAX literally means nothing to me as I am still new to the world of web programming.

Comment: @SomeStudent Then google it to find a tutorial. SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: If you use jQuery, you can do it with a one-liner.

Comment: `$("#meaning").load("scriptname.php");`

Comment: Okay, did see that before, now, the script does have the function in it, how to access the function?

Comment: It only means nothing to you because you can't be bothered looking it up, and if you can't be bothered, why should we?

Comment: Google search AJAX. First bit, a description of what AJAX is. First result, jQuery documentation with examples of how to do it. Just sayin'.

Comment: Oh aye, did that. However, one cannot fully grasp it immediately. Using the .onload is fine, it works great if it is a single file and you are just fetch its entirety. However, still uncertain how to grab the specific function and its return value.

Comment: AJAX is just HTTP requests, you make a request, you get a response, so think of it that way. If you want a specific function to be called, your PHP needs to have a way to know that that's what you're after. That might be via some routing logic, or it might be calling a specific PHP file, just as examples.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Ajax
In short, it is from the front (Javascript) to the back-end (PHP) value
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp
or google
jQuery AJAX

Comment: What in the name of all that is good and holy... someone is actually referencing jQuery on w3schools!